# What's wrong with the following logic in deducing these polynomials are zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

As part of a larger question in a tutorial, we proved that if some polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ was in the kernel of some homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Q}[X,Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[T]$, we have $A(T^2) + B(T^2)T^3 = 0$, where $A,B\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. (Here $A,B$ are polynomials related to the representation of $f$, but I don't think the specifics matter for this question).

A subquestion was to show that if some polynomial $f$ is in the kernel, then the polynomials $A$ and $B$ are zero. This wasn't too hard; we already proved that if $f \in \text{Ker} \phi$, then $A(T^2) + B(T^2)T^3 = 0$. We just have to realise then that all the powers of $T$ in $A(T^2)$ are even, while they are odd in $B(T^2)T^3$. So the only way for the sum to be zero is if both $A$ and $B$ are zero.

**The issue:**
I was wondering about another way to see this. Clearly if $A,B \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ then $A[T^2],B[T^2] \in \mathbb{Q}[T]$. In this case, I don't see why we can't think of $A(T^2) + B(T^2)T^3$ as being an element of $(\mathbb{Q}[T])[T]$. That is, as a polynomial in $T$, with coefficients as polynomials in $T$. Formally, the polynomial can be seen as the sequence $(A(T^2),0,0,B(T^2),0,0,...)$. My reasoning then was that clearly if this sequence is the zero polynomial, i.e. $(0,0,0,...)$, then $A(T^2)$ and $B(T^2)$ must be the zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$, and we are done.

But I realised that this logic is clearly faulty. For example, suppose instead we have $A(T^2) + B(T^2)T^2 = 0$, so now the original odd/even argument wouldn't hold. By my second argument, this polynomial formally is the sequence $(A(T^2),0,B(T^2),0,0,0,...)$, which by my reasoning would again force $A(T^2) = B(T^2) = 0$, since $(A(T^2),0,B(T^2),0,0,0,...) = (0,0,0,...)$. But this isn't true, because taking $A(X) = X$ and $B(X) = -1$, we can clearly see that $A(T^2) + B(T^2)T^2 = 0$.

**What exactly is going on here?** I am sure that the argument is flawed, but I cannot identify why. I know it's strange to consider the ring $(\mathbb{Q}[T])[T]$, since it's just isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[T]$, but I don't see why that should matter. The crux of the issue here to me is that if we consider any polynomial formally, it's just an eventually $0$ sequence, where the terms of the sequence are elements of the underlying ring of the polynomial ring. All that to say that if $(a_1,a_2,0,0,0...) = (b_1,b_2,0,0,0,...)$, we MUST have $a_1 = b_1$ and $a_2 = b_2$ by the very definition of what a polynomial is. But that doesn't seem to hold in this case?

Comment: Just as a note: you can consider $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ as an extension of the subring $\mathbb{Q}[T^2]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All that to say that if $(a_1,a_2,0,0,0...)=(b_1,b_2,0,0,0,...)$, we MUST have $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$ by the very definition of what a polynomial is. But that doesn't seem to hold in this case?

Indeed that is the problem, and it lies at the core of why $(\mathbb Q[T])[T]$ does not really make sense. The notation makes it difficult to even discuss the problem, though. If the two $T$s in $(\mathbb Q[T])[T]$ are supposed to be *different*, then this ring is just $\mathbb Q[X, Y]$ with extremely confusing notation. If you intend for this ring to be $\mathbb Q[T]$, but just treating some of the $T$s different from others to mimic arguments that you might make about $\mathbb Q[X, Y]$, then even very basic 'facts' turn out to be false. Indeed, the sequences $(T, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ and $(0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots)$ become equal, which they would not in ordinary ("actual") polynomial rings.

Comment: Thank you, I've thought about it for a while and I think I see your point. However, in the latter case you describe, is there anyway to see why exactly such a 'polynomial ring' is not really? I get that it fails to satisfy the typical facts we expect from these rings, but I still cannot place my finger on why it fails in this case?

Comment: @masiewpao, that is a difficult question. One very technical answer you could give is that $(T, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) = (0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots)$ is *exactly the point of failure*, in the sense that if you are looking at $R = (\mathbb Q[T_1])[T_2]$ as a set of $\mathbb Q[T_1]$-sequences, and you let $I \subseteq R$ be the ideal generated by the relation $(T_1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) = (0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, or equivalently by the element $(T_1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, or equivalently by the element $T_1 - T_2$, then $R/I \cong \mathbb Q[T]$ (via $T_1 \mapsto T, T_2 \mapsto T$).

Comment: Thanks very much!